# Which tense is the correct one hear when describing something that could or will happen in the future?

Tags: tense

I am intrigued by people using different tenses when talking about the future.
I heard native speakers use tenses differently. I will try to give an example using an example sentence:

"The good thing about Spotify is that you get to know a lot of new music because the program starts playing music which is like the one you chose and you get to know music that you never heard!"
"The good thing about Spotify is that you will get to know a lot of new music because the program starts playing music which is like the one you chose and you will get to know music that you have never heard!

First, there is no usage of the will future in the first sentence. Shouldn´t it be used here? Can you really use the simple present only?

In the second version, the "because sentence" doesn´t use "will" as well as the "that sentence" in the next sentence that follows. I was told you shouldn´t use "will" in a dependent sentence when it has already been used in the independent one that comes before or after the dependent one? Is that right?

Second, the first sentence uses the simple past at the very end: "...you have never heard!" while the second one uses the present perfect.

It should be the present perfect, shouldn´t it? Music that one has never heard until that point in time.

Or is the future perfect ("...will have never heard before!"?

I am bit confused about this!

Comment: Anglophones in general don't care as much about "verb tense" as speakersa of many other languages. In fact, it's often pointed out that English only has two basic tenses (Present, and "Not Present"). We can get *much* more creatively interested in ***modal*** forms *(should, could, would*, etc.), because choices made there can genuinely affect intended and/or received meaning. But if the only reason for using a given "tense" is that it's syntactically / logically required, the choice probably doesn't actually ***mean*** anything, so people will tend to ignore it as "semantically irrelevant".

Comment: Well, I still need to know on a formal level because I will have to teach grammar in the future.

Comment: ...anyway, I don't know if it's something to do with how *your* language works in such contexts, but for your cited example I can't see any good reason for claiming it should involve ***future*** tense. The guy is talking about something which ***is*** a good thing about Spotify, Note that his use of ***you*** is potentially ambiguous, since it might refer to ***people in general*** (who may indeed be currently experiencing the benefit) or the specific person(s) being addressed (who again may already be Spotify users or not; we just don't know).

Comment: I see. That makes sense to me because it describes a fact that is true in general. But what about using the simple past or present perfect?

Comment: Also note that.even if the speaker were actually trying to persuade someone to start using Spotify (so by implication, he's talking about benefits the other person ***will*** experience), he might choose to use modal ***would*** or ***could***, both of which can carry subtly different implications. As would the simpler ***will***, but these are subtle nuances, not really matters of "grammatical rules".

Comment: When in doubt, the best bet is usually to use the simplest verb form that's remotely credible. And Simple Present is perfectly "credible" in many contexts where you could ***justify*** using a more complex form. People teaching grammar tend to err on the side of promoting "more exact" tenses, but native speakers routinely ignore such advice.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean to say but could you tell me what the difference between using the simple past or the present perfect at the end of the sentences would be or if you should really use the future perfect here when trying to convince someone to use Spotify?

Comment: I know my comments are dragging on a bit, but... I'd just like to flag up the fact that your cited (perfectly competent) native speaker ***didn't*** choose to explicitly specify "future" by saying *the program **will start to play** [potentially interesting music]*. Personally, I think doing that would slightly amplify the "nuance" that it's a *continuous, gradually improving* feature, which isn't really present in his "simplified" version.

Comment: Well, using the will future usually means to be really sure of the thing you are talking about. That is how I interpret it. I mean that this will be a great benefit to the other guy and enrich his music experience.

Comment: I´d really like to know about the rule of using will here too, as well as the simple past or present perfect part of my question if you know the formal rules for that.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to know about "nuances", I should just point out that there's quite a difference in *real-world meaning* between *music you have never heard* and *music you have never heard **of***. Strictly speaking, there's a good "logical" case for the Perfect there, and many speakers often if not always *would*. But in the exact context, he's already "anchored" in the Present *you **get** to know*, chronologically following Past *the one you **chose***. Introducing yet another Past via Present Perfect is do-able, but I like the simpler version better. They all mean the same anyway.

Comment: I accidentally put the "of" in. I edited it.

Comment: Re *using the **will** future usually means to be really sure of the thing you are talking about*, that's not really true. It's often contextually *necessary / useful* to explicitly indicate Future, regardless of "certainty" - which you can tell by the fact that there are many contexts where in speech the word ***will*** can be given heavy stress to make it clear that's the important word, carrying the full weight of its *possible* nuance. If it *always* had that implication, there'd be no need to stress the word to isolate and amplify that sense.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/will

Comment: I´ts a prediction here and will is supposed to be stronger than "would" if you check practically any grammar book. That´s what I was taught in school.

Comment: As I said, I ***don't*** know that it's a prediction (as opposed to speaker pointing out the benefits he and his audience *currently* enjoy). But even if we accept that the speaker is talking about *future* benefits, that doesn't imply he must explicitly mark that fact by using ***will***. Nor does it imply that if he *did* use it, ***will*** would unambiguously emphasise the fact that he's making a "prediction" (whatever that itself might imply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stating a general truth or state of affairs the present tense is often used. So the statement about Spotify that uses the present is not about a future experience but about the Spotify experience in general.

When the periphrastic future with **will** is used, the speaker's emphasis is on what can be *expected* by someone who tries Spotify.

Language expresses thought.